# What is the "Parameters" field of an AWS Glue Data Catalog table column?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, parquet

The AWS documentation for Glue Data Catalog tables notes that a column has four fields:

- Name
- Type
- Comment
- Parameters

The first three are easy enough to understand; here is an excerpt from my CloudFormation template:

```yaml
# . . . the full table definition has been elided . . .

StorageDescriptor:
    Columns:
        - { Name: id, Type: string, Comment: "A unique key; UUIDv4" }
```

However, I am unclear as to what *Parameters* should be used for.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-Column

I have copied and pasted the documentation section in question below:

```
Column structure
    A column in a Table.

Fields

    Name
        - Required: UTF-8 string, not less than 1 or more than 255 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern.
        - The name of the Column. 

    Type
        – UTF-8 string, not more than 131072 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern.
        - The data type of the Column.

    Comment
        – Comment string, not more than 255 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern.
        - A free-form text comment.

    Parameters
        – A map array of key-value pairs. Each key is a Key string, not less than 1 or more than 255 bytes long, matching the Single-line string pattern. Each value is a UTF-8 string, not more than 512000 bytes long. These key-value pairs define properties associated with the column.
```

However, *Parameters* doesn't appear in the CloudFormation documentation available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-table-column.html

**Questions:**

1. What are *Parameters*?
2. Are they documented anywhere?
3. Could you please provide an example?
4. What should I include in the *Parameters*, and why might it be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Parameters field is useful for storing additional metadata about a column that is not captured by the Name, Type, or Comment fields

So you can use it to define properties associated with a column in the table

The AWS Glue documentation provides a list of parameters that are set by AWS Glue crawlers. you can this list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/table-properties-crawler.html)

These parameters include:

- classification: Format of data, inferred by the crawler.
- compressionType: Type of compression used on data in the table.
- objectCount: Number of objects under Amazon S3 path for table.
- recordCount: Estimate the count of records in the table, based on file sizes
  and headers.
- sizeKey: Combined size of files in table crawled.
- typeOfData: File, table, or view.

For example, if you have a column named data in a table named my_table, you can set the typeOfData parameter for the data column to file if the column contains file data, table if the column contains table data, or view if the column contains view data.